# Database table result compare

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I am doing

`select count(*) from DATA_TABLE where jobid=1` . Its giving me 10000 records.

and

`select count(*) from DATA_TABLE where jobid=2` . Its giving me 12500 records.

Now I want to see that extra 2500 records. How do I do it ?

Note : that 10000 records should be same as I run same logic.

Comment: Extra 2500? But are you sure all 10000 job 1 rows are included in the 12500 job 2 rows?

Comment: How does a single row in the table have a job_id of both 1 and 2?

Comment: Do you want to **see each of the 2500 rows themselves** OR **see the number 2500, which is the difference in number of rows**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MINUS operator

```
select column_list from DATA_TABLE where jobid=2
MINUS
select column_list from DATA_TABLE where jobid=1
```

Comment: No, `SELECT  *` inclides the `jobid` column too. So, the MINUS will return all the rows from table where jobid is 2.

Answer (score 3):

Doing a `SELECT *` would anyway give you all the columns, thus the **MINUS** would consider all the rows to be different and you will have all the rows in the result.

You must include only those columns which you want to take a difference.

For example,

```
SELECT column_list from DATA_TABLE where jobid=1
MINUS
SELECT column_list from DATA_TABLE where jobid=2
```

**Make sure the `column_list` doesn't include `jobid` column.**